# подскажите пожалуйста где можно прочитать о спред и рест операторы перед именем функции как в данном примере

Tags: javascript

```
function flatten(arr) {
    let array = [];

    if (условие) {
            array.push(...flatten(item));
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-spread-rest

Comment: @UModeL спасибо за ссылку, но к сожалению там нет объяснения что означает рест оперетор перед самой функцией, не могу нигде найти объяснение

Comment: @Марта функция возвращает массив, а рест относится к массиву, вот и всё. То есть рест применяется не к функции, а к результату, который возвращает функция

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, буду разбираться